# Append elements to matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, append, cells

I want to make a matrix like this:

```
n rows x 2 columns

22.3 18.3
22.4 18.4
22.5 18.3
22.4 18.3
22.2 18.6
```

In this case I have **5 rows by 2 columns**

But I need to append a **new row dynamically**, removing the first based in a given window I want.

e.g. I have a window of N elements in row, when I append the new row in the matrix, I must remove the first one.

In the above example, a window of **5 rows**:
If I need to input (append) the new row: 22.8 17.1 the row will become like this:

```
22.3 18.3
22.4 18.4
22.5 18.3
22.4 18.3
22.2 18.6
22.8 17.1
```

There are **6 rows**, I need to remove the first one. After that the row becomes like this **(5 rows)**:

```
22.4 18.4
22.5 18.3
22.4 18.3
22.2 18.6
22.8 17.1
```

My question:
- how to append a new row in matlab?
- how to remove a new row in matlab?

I saw that in matlab It's possible to handle matrix vectors and cells.

E.g
I achieved What I want doing that:

```
messageArr = [];
messageArr{end+1} = 23.01
messageArr{end+1} = 23.02
messageArr = messageArr.';%'//
messageArr{end+1} = 23.03
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr{end+1} = 23.04
messageArr2 = [];
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.01
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.02
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.03
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2{end+1} = 17.04
messageArr2 = messageArr2.'%'//
Y = horzcat(messageArr, messageArr2)
Y = cell2mat(Y)
```

It gave me a 13x2 double matrix:

```
23,0100000000000    17,0100000000000
23,0200000000000    17,0200000000000
23,0300000000000    17,0300000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
23,0400000000000    17,0400000000000
```

But I think this is not the right way to do it.
I need a more simple way to just append, and remove the first row without the necessity of concate cells and doing transpose of cells.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're using a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html) instead of a [matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html)? See [concatenation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html), you managed to find `horzcat`, why not try `vertcat`? I would start by putting together your full matrix, checking its [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html), and then delete the rows you don't want.

Comment: What you show is not a matrix but a cell array. This two are fundamentally different in MATLAB. I think you want a matrix!

Comment: Is it? I opened the matlab's window and just copied.
It was like this 13x2 double
I think it represents it as cell when you double click the variable it creates in the workspace.

Comment: In MATLAB to get rid of a row you execute `Y(rowIdx,:) = []` . The `end` keyword may also come in handy here `Y = [Y(end-3:end,;) ; newRow]` will give you a moving window of size 5

Comment: @felipe using curly  brackets `{}` casts the empty array as a cell. If it wasn't a cell then `cell2mat` wouldn't be needed...

Comment: I need the input to be a matrix because of the funciton I'm using (numObs-by-numDims matrix )

Comment: @excaza Cell Array is not the same (in memory) as matrix in matalb? I always managed to program java C++, the matrix is the name to a multidimentional array. I didn't know the type Cell Array is a complete diferent format.

Comment: @felipe If this is the case then why did you use `cell2mat`? What did you think that was doing?

Comment: @beaker I thought it was the same think in memory, just a format for handling data should be different. I'm trying to find how to directly create a matrix instead of Cell Array;

Comment: `Y = [23.01 17.01; 23.02 17.02; 23.03 17.03]`

Comment: @beaker Two dimentional Nx2 (n rows x columns) and appending elements to it how to do?

Comment: `BigMat = [BigMat ; NewRow]` You need to read a basic MATLAB tutorial. You can start here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html

Comment: @beaker ok you're right I got it; the documentation clarified everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will append a new row and remove the first row:

```
% create five rows of two-column data
d=[22.3 18.3; 22.4 18.4; 22.5 18.3; 22.4 18.3; 22.2 18.6]
% this is a new row of data
newrow = [22.8 17.1]
% drop the first row and append the new data at the end
d = [d(2:end,:); newrow]
```

It uses the [ ] [concatentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/redefining-concatenation-for-your-class.html) operator.